# Issue with template argument deduction

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction

I have a quite simple template problem.
I wanted to have some mathematical functions that work with scalars and vectors. For arguments, I want my scalars to be passed by copy, and my vectors by reference.
So I ended up using a templated helper struct.

But when I use my functions, the compiler does not manage to deduce template parameters by itself.
I don't know what I did wrong, or what I should do differently, or if this approach is doomed from the beginning ^^'.

Here is an example:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct CopyOrConstRef
{
    using Type = std::conditional_t<
                    std::is_scalar<T>::value,
                    T,
                    const std::remove_reference_t<T>&
                 >;
};
template <typename T>
using CopyOrConstRef_t = typename CopyOrConstRef<T>::Type;

template <typename T>
T Lerp(CopyOrConstRef_t<T> _a, CopyOrConstRef_t<T> _b, const float _factor)
{
    return (_a * (1.f - _factor)) + (_b * _factor);
}

int main()
{
    Lerp(0.f, 1.f, 0.5f); // does not work :'(
    Lerp<float>(0.f, 1.f, 0.5f); // works as intended

    return 0;
}
```

With error messages (on msvc):

```
error C2672: 'Lerp': no matching overloaded function found
error C2783: 'T Lerp(CopyOrConstRef<T>::Type,CopyOrConstRef<T>::Type,const float)': could not deduce template argument for 'T'
```

Comment: That's not really how template argument deduction works. It always matches on the exact type without any conversions. You are passing `float` and the function will only take some form of `CopyOrConstRef<...>` so deduction fails.

Comment: So, I'm doomed in the beginning? :,D
Is there some way to achieve what I tried to do?

Comment: Passing `float` by const ref is generally not an issue, in particular with template. Chance are that the function call be inlined anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work, since all the uses of `T` (which are `CopyOrConstRef_t<T>`) in the argument list of `Lerp` are in [non-deduced contexts](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.type#5.1):

> The non-deduced contexts are:
>
> > The nested-name-specifier of a type that was specified using a qualified-id.

---

Here's an [example](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.type#18) from the reference:

> Template parameters do not participate in template argument deduction if they are used only in non-deduced contexts. For example,
>
> ```
> template<int i, typename T>
> T deduce(typename A<T>::X x,    // T is not deduced here
>         T t,                    // but T is deduced here
>         typename B<i>::Y y);    // i is not deduced here
> ```

Your example is the same, except that there is no argument that can be deduced, and you have an alias template for the arguments (which doesn't change anything).